# It is possible to rewrite MatrixCursor to pass blob data?

Tags: android, matrixcursor

I don't want the blob data which is retrieved from the server to be stored in the database and I know that `MatrixCursor` cannot deliver this kind of data. Could anyone help me out of this?

Answer (score 0):

Grab the source code to `MatrixCursor`, modify it, move it to your own package (e.g., `com.silenthawk`), and use it. It's less than 300 lines, including comments and whitespace.